# Why no warning is issued when storing the output of strlen in an int?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

The type `strlen` returns is `size_t`, which is `long unsigned int`.

Why compiling the following code does not issue a warning about the signedness of `slen`?

```
char msg[] = "Hello";
int slen= strlen(msg);
```

(I expected that `long unsigned int slen` would have been necessary to avoid such a warning.)

Comment: Probably depends on your compiler settings.

Comment: Because it doesn't have to. This conversion is perfectly legal.

Comment: [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for GCC

Comment: `size_t` happens to be `unsigned long int` in the implementation you're using. It doesn't have to be. It just has to be some unsigned integer type big enough to hold the size of an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C and C++ languages let you copy integers between all the different types without a warning (compilers could give you a warning by default, some do with `char`, which is a notorious exception).

With `gcc` you can use this warning to avoid losing the upper bits (so `long long` to `int` will give you a warning on 32bit machines).

```sh
gcc ... -Wstrict-overflow ...
```

There is also a flag to prevent automatic conversions:

```sh
gcc ... -Wno-int-conversion ...
```

which is likely to cause a lot of compilation problems, but it can be a good idea to test your code (a *lint* type of thing).

Looking at the `gcc` manual will give you other details about these warnings.

Note that you can also use the `-Werror` flag to transform warnings into errors. That way the compilation fails instead of letting you go on with things that you would consider a bug.

Comment: "By default, C and C++ let you copy integers between all the different types without a warning" -- It would be more accurate to say that the language doesn't *require* a warning. Compilers can warn about anything they like, and the C standard says nothing about what a compiler's default behavior should be. It just requires conforming compilers to issue diagnostics for violations of syntax rules and constraints (which this isn't) -- and many compilers are not even conforming by default.